# How to use Mongodb aggregation framework to find number combinations regardless of order

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Is it possible to use mongodb to calculate the number of times a combination is used for particular fields regardless of the order? In my case I want to total all documents that have the same item numbers, regardless of what order the numbers are in. for example [5,4,3] and [4,3,5] are regarded as the same because they have the same numbers.

In my schema example I'd like to find the id's of all items that are the same (regardless of their order). From there I'd like to calculate the percent that are 'online'.

For example I have this schema

```
{
 id: 5,
 online: true,
 item1: 432,
 item2: 314,
 item3: 453,
 item4: 324,
 item5: 238,
 item6: 138
}

{ 
 id: 6, 
 online: false,
 item1: 314, //same as above just with item 1 and 2 swapped around
 item2: 432,
 item3: 453,
 item4: 324,
 item5: 238,
 item6: 138
}

{ 
 id: 7, //no match
 online: true,
 item1: 394,
 item2: 432,
 item3: 3253,
 item4: 324,
 item5: 218,
 item6: 438
}
return [5,6],[7]
```

To be completely honest, I'm not even sure where to start for this, so any help would be much appreciated :) Thanks,

Joel.

Comment: Why didn't you just use an array `items` to store the item numbers instead of having fields with names like `item1`, `item2` etc.? That would make this (and likely many other things) a lot easier because you could use all the useful [set operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-set/).

Comment: I was aggregating data from an external api which provided the data in this format, I'll have a look into the set operators and see if I can change my existing data into this format. Thanks :)